# Restriction of a zero divisor may not be a zero divisor, and restriction of a non-zero-divisor may be a zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Am I correct that localising $k[x,y]/(xy)$ at $S=\{x,x^2,\dots\}$ gives:
$$(k[x,y]/(xy))_{x}\cong k[x,x^{-1},y]/(y)\cong k[x,x^{-1}]?$$
My only confusion is that $x\in k[x,y]/(xy)$ is a zero divisor, and yet its image in the localisation is not.

Probably this is reasonable, since the two axes scheme $\text{Spec}(K[x,y]/(xy))$ has affine open subscheme $$D(x)=\text{Spec}(k[x,x^{-1}])\cong \Bbb A^1_K\backslash\{0\},$$ which is just the $x$-axis remove the origin, which is integral, so has no zero divisors.

Similarly, let $X$ be a scheme and $U$ some open subset. Let $s\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ be a non-zero-divisor. Is it possible that $\rho^U_V(s)\in\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ is a zero divisor?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Thanks for confirming the first half!

Comment: For the second part, the answer is no. A non-zero divisor remains a non-zero divisor when restricted to a non-empty open set.

Comment: $\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}$Localization may lose zero-divisors. The localization map may not be injective (unlike in the case of integral domains). Easiest example is when you localize $A=\Z/6\Z$ (with zero-divisors) with $S=\{1,2,4\}\bmod 6$ you get a ring that is isomorphic to the field $\Z/3\Z$

Comment: Proof @Mohan? $\,$

Comment: Multiplication by $s$ is injective from $O_U$ to itself and restriction to open sets is exact.